# How to create a dummy account for App Store Connect review

Tags: ios

I have apple signin on my app that im trying to submit but in order to get approved I need to provide a dummy account that they can use to review the app.  However when I create an apple id it has 2-factor authentication enabled so they wouldnt be able to use it for login.

Comment: If your app simply uses an Apple ID I believe that you can tell them that and testers will have test Apple ids that they can use, particularly if it is for IAP.

Answer (score 1):

Sign in to App Store Connect.
On the homepage, click Users and Access.
Under Sandbox, click Testers.
Click “+” to set up your tester accounts.
Complete the tester information form and click Invite.
Sign out of your Apple ID on all testing devices and sign back in with your new sandbox tester account.

Comment: Thanks, ill try that out and submit it for review and see if they can log in